# Inconsistent behaviour on a fake(interface vs abstract class) using fakeiteasy

Tags: interface, abstract-class, fakeiteasy

I had following code

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Execute();
}

public abstract class FooBar: IFoo
{
    public void Execute()
    {
         OnExecute();
    }  

    public abstract void OnExecute();
}
```

and following test case to test the `Execute()` method

```
[Fact]
public void When_execute_method_called_Expect_executionTime_is_set()
{
    var sutMethod = A.Fake<FooBar>();

    A.CallTo(sutMethod).
                Where(x => x.Method.Name == "OnExecute").
                Invokes(x => Thread.Sleep(100)));

    sutMethod.Execute();

    Assert.NotEqual(0, sutMethod.Result.ExecutionTime.Ticks);
}
```

`sutMethod.Execute();` call would go to `FooBar.Execute()`

later I decided to make the interface into an **abstract class**

```
public abstract class IFoo
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}

public abstract class FooBar:IFoo
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
         OnExecute();
    }  

    public abstract void OnExecute();
}
```

Now `sutMethod.Execute();` call does not invoke `FooBar.Execute()`

I thought FakeItEasy would handles interface and abstract classes as equal.What am I missing?

**Update**
@ Blair Conrad provided the reasoning for the behaviour

Is it possible to make minimal changes to the test case to get the original behaviour back?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is due to the overrideability of the method `Execute` on `FooBar`.
FakeItEasy [can only override virtual members, abstract members, or interface members](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden).

In your original example, when `IFooBar` is an interface and `FooBar` implements it, `Execute` is a concrete method. It's not virtual, nor is it abstract. Thus FakeItEasy can't intercept calls to it, and the original method is executed.

Once you change `IFooBar` to an abstract class, you have an abstract `IFooBar.Execute`, which you `override` in `FooBar`. As such, `FooBar.Execute` is now virtual and can be intercepted by FakeItEasy. Which it does, so your implementation is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Following addition help solve the issue

```
A.CallTo(() => sutMethod.Execute()).CallsBaseMethod();
```

This calls the virtual method `Execute`of `FooBar`